# Use an L293D with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, l293d

I am making a 2-wheeled Arduino car controlled by T.V. remote for a science fair tomorrow. I have found a tutorial for the IR part. I brought this  [L293D motor driver](https://www.amazon.in/Maker-Hacker-MBRIDGEV-H-Bridge-Raspberry/dp/B01CBD52QA) to control a 2-wheeled car. I am facing a problem. I know where to connect the motors (because there are indications stating M1 and M2) but I don't know where to connect the motor driver to the Arduino and to the batteries.

I checked over the net but couldn't find any tutorial for this kind of board. Also I have no experience in all this so I don't want to risk it. I don't want any code or anything, just where to connect what.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE. Please realize that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway.

Comment: I searched all over the net for any documentation but i didn't find any. That's why i turned here

Comment: What have you done already? (Beside having various hardware pieces)

Comment: @LookAlterno I connected the 2 wires of motor 1 to the two headers stating M1 and connected the 2 wires of motor 2 to the two headers stating M2. I found the hex values of the Buttons of the I.R. remote and have connected the I.R.(TSOP 1738) receiver to the Arduino. I also found a tutorial but am yet to program the chip cause i want to finish the joining of the components first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the inputs are clearly marked.

The battery connects to +12V and GND
The Arduino's 5V and GND connect to 5V and GND.

The control signals connect to the header of control signals. ENx is the PWM signal for the speed for motor X. IN1/IN2 are the direction/brake controls for motor 1, and IN3/IN4 are the direction/brake controls for motor 2.

The signal labels are exactly the same as the pin names for the chip and match up precisely with every single tutorial on the net for using the L293D with the Arduino.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have a question. Can I power the Arduino with a 1.5 volt and the motor driver with two 9 volts battery.

Comment: No, and maybe. If the motor is 18V then yes. The Arduino can never run from 1.5V. It needs 5V minimum.